# Convert multiple columns to Datetime at once keeping just the time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to change multiple columns to the same datatype at once,
columns contain time data like hours minute and seconds, like
And the data

[image]

and I'm not able to change multiple columns at once to using **`pd.to_datetime`** to only the time format, I don't want the date because, if I do **`pd.to_datetime`** the date also gets added to the column which is not required, just want the time
how to convert the column to DateTime and only keep time in the column

Comment: You can't have a DateTime column with only time in it.

Answer (score 1):

First **You can't have a datetime with only time in it in pandas/python**.

So

Because python time is object in pandas convert all columns to datetimes (but there are also dates):

```
cols = ['Total Break Time','col1','col2']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Or convert columns to timedeltas, it looks like similar times, but possible working by datetimelike methods in pandas:

```
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_timedelta)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pick only `time` as below:

```
import time
df['Total Break Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Total Break Time'],format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.time
```

Then you can repeat this for all your columns, as I suppose you already are.

The catch is, to convert to `datetime` and then only picking out what you need.

Comment: even after doing that the data-type is still an object

Comment: @SanchayBhargava - Yes, it is expected, time is object in pandas

Comment: I thought I would display DateTime as datatype, thanks @jezrael

Comment: @SanchayBhargava do you want it to be string or something? How do you want the data-type to be?

Comment: @jezrael what if I have a Dataframe with 450 columns containing datetime objects?
If I do df['col'].dt.time it works but if I do df.dt.time or df.values.dt.time I get errors
( error 1: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'
  error 2:'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dt')